# Approximation of a function from its integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a non negative continuous function and $c$ be a sufficiently small positive number (close to $0$) such that,
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f dx<c$. can we say $ f< g(c) $ for all $ s\in \mathbb{R}$, where g is a function such that $g(c)>0$?

Any help or hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, consider a sequence of spikes going off to infinity with shrinking bases and increasing heights. You can arrange these so that the integral is as small as you want, but $f$ will still be unbounded.

Comment: Thanks. Got it.